# Python Statsmodels quasi-information criteria qic. Any example?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I must be doing something really wrong, for I just cannot write a code to get the quasi-information criteria from python statsmodels GEE method "qic". This method is listed the same way as the method "fit"  (http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE) used in the code below:

```
model2 = sm.GEE.from_formula("BPXSY1 ~ RIDAGEYR + RIAGENDRx + BMXBMI + C(RIDRETH1)",groups="group",cov_struct=sm.cov_struct.Exchangeable(), data=da)
result2 = model2.fit()
```

But if I code "qic" the same way I coded "fit" the script does not run and the following message comes up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b3cc871449c1> in <module>()
----> 1 criteria = model2.qic()

AttributeError: 'GEE' object has no attribute 'qic'
```

I have also tried:

```
criteria = model2.qic(result2.params)
```

and:

```
criteria = result2.qic()
```

Nothing works. I get always the same Error message. It must be a syntax mistake. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Do you have statsmodels version 0.10 or newer?

Comment: Hi, I have Statsmodels 0.10.2 version

Comment: Hello, I managed to find out what the problem was, and it was a matter of statsmodels version. Version 0.11.1, the one I have now, does run propery the last comand I mentioned in my question above. Sorry for not checking that before posting.